What are some strategies for encoding a topology in Coq?
Topologies are the simplest example I can think of of a mathematical object that's fundamentally non-first-order.
I'm curious what some strategies are for encoding topologies or topological spaces in Coq.
I'm especially curious if there's essentially one way that's convenient for doing real work in Coq or if there are a few competing ways with different tradeoffs.
I'm also curious how you avoid accidentally encoding something that isn't a topology. For example, this question I asked three and a half years ago does not encode a topology, it encodes a definable approximation to a topology.
My gut tells me that the considerations here are kind of subtle, because you can definitely talk about topologies in ZFC, which is itself a first-order theory. I suspect that as long as you never step outside the bounds of the system that you are working in then you don't run into problems. That does mean, however, that when working in a constructive system you need to be careful to match impedance with the system as a whole when talking about arbitrary unions, otherwise you are leaving out some unions that are visible to the system in some vague sense.

Here is a very basic stab at encoding a topology in Coq that does not use any advanced features at all.
It is painful to use because you have to pass around pretopologies (what I'm calling families of sets) and proofs that they are topologies.
It's also limited. It can't encode lattices-with-finite-meets-and-arbitrary-joins that can't be encoded as sets of opens. (which might be relevant if you're working with locales or whatever. I don't understand locales at all, but I know there are things out there that out there with the meet/join asymmetry of topologies that nevertheless can't be represented as topologies)
(* This is intentionally an extremely naive encoding of a topological space in Coq.

I could not decide whether to encode the arbitrary union using exists or some kind of
double negation translation thing.
 *)


(* pretopology is a family of sets *)
Definition pretopology a : Type := (a -> Prop) -> Prop.

(* empty set is in a topology *)
Definition pt_empty a : (a -> Prop) := fun _ => False.

(* full set is in a topology *)
Definition pt_full a : (a -> Prop) := fun _ => True.

(* binary intersections are in a topology.
   finite intersections are iterated binary intersections *)
Definition pt_binary_intersection {a} (f g : a -> Prop) : a -> Prop := fun x => f x /\ g x.

(* arbitrary (constructive) union *)
Definition pt_arbitrary_union {a} (F : (a -> Prop) -> Prop) : a -> Prop :=
  fun x => exists f, F f /\ f x.

(*

   straightforward encoding of the axioms of a topology.
   1) empty set is in T
   2) full set is in T
   3) binary (or finite) intersections are in T
   4) arbitrary unions are in T

 *)
Definition topology {a} (pt : pretopology a) :=
  pt (pt_empty a) /\
  pt (pt_full a) /\
  (forall x y, pt x -> pt y -> pt (pt_binary_intersection x y)) /\
  (forall F, (forall f, F f -> pt f) -> pt (pt_arbitrary_union F)).
```


I'd recommend using a structure/record over a bunch of ∧. Also, the definition of top spaces in the arend-lib might interest you: https://github.com/JetBrains/arend-lib/blob/master/src/Topology/TopSpace.ard

Why don't you use typeclass? Here is an example: https://github.com/PnVDiscord/PnVRocqLib/blob/1e4072cca1c5659cad43193eb22ae11774431a7d/theories/Prelude/Prelude.v#L1301
